# double-click to run .sh file

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

GUI:
I changed the permissions of an sh file, so that I can read, write and execute it.
I double-clicked it, selected run in Shell / terminal (whichever appears in english), but it didn't run.
I double-clicked it, selected run, but it didn't run.

Command-Line:
`bash *filename*` runs it
`sh *filename*` runs it

The file content is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# get dirsyncpro home
DIRSYNCPRO_HOME="$(dirname $0)"

# start programm and pass any parameters
java -Xmx512M -jar "$DIRSYNCPRO_HOME/dirsyncpro.jar" $*
```

Works in this person's computer:

http://www.knowliz.com/2008/08/how-to-installrun-sh-file-in-linux.html

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dirsyncpro readme says that it must be run by command-line in all non-Windows operating systems. I was avoiding running the jar file, but there's no other way.

Answer (score 7):

Your test is wrong, you must be able to run it without first calling another shell.

```
./my_little_script.sh
```

And not

```
bash my_little_script.sh
```

Also double check that the permissions actually is correct.

```
chmod 755 my_little_script.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when you try to run your shell script by double clicking it, your system by default will run it in your home directory.

When arriving at the line

```
# start programm and pass any parameters
java -Xmx512M -jar "$DIRSYNCPRO_HOME/dirsyncpro.jar" $*
```

The `DIRSYNCPRO_HOME` folder is not the folder you expect, your jar file is not found and the application will silently stop. I think if you hardcode the value of `DIRSYNPRO_HOME` you should be able to run your shell script with doubleclicking it.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, "Terminal" doesn't really exist. On my install (9.10) I get this:

The program 'Terminal' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install terminal.app  Terminal: command not found

I'm not sure if that is the case for you, but if it is try changing the select from "Termianl" to "gnome-terminal".

Comment: i think "Terminal" in this context is a Gnome/freedesktop capability, not a specific application.  similar to Apt's concept of virtual packages, *gnome-terminal* and *urxvt* and other packages "provide" the Terminal capability.  my karmic VM is currently offline but i think such capabilities are defined in the *.desktop files under /usr/share/applications or similar.

Comment: Terminal in brazilian porguese may be Shell in american english.  It's where you type Linux commands.

Comment: @Delirium: no, shell is something different.  terminal is what displays the output of command-line programs; shell is what provides and interprets the command-line.  *gnome-terminal* and PuTTY are terminals; bash and tcsh are shells.  where you type linux commands generally includes both a shell and a terminal.

Comment: Googling for double click sh results in "I could run the script from terminal." - http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/redhat-fedora-linux-help/160662-shell-script-execution-double-click.html "You'd run in in a terminal." - http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1107371.html "Its intended to be used through terminal:" - http://cerebrux.comli.com/2clickupdate/english-version/ "how can I make it so that it runs in a terminal" - http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/running-sh-script-by-double-clicking-52229/ People are using Terminal all the time. How come it's wrong?

Comment: @Delirium: they're just two closely related, but distinctly different things.  the terminal gives you a window to run the shell in; the shell interprets your command and runs other programs; the terminal displays what those programs output.

Comment: @Delirium tremens: I don't think its wrong. What I think is wrong is that your desktop manager doesn't really know what do with it when you double click it. There is a bad association with what program to run when you double click on a .sh file.